# Prove that for an infinite uncountable set $M$ and infinite countable set $B$: $M \sim M \cup B$

Tags: functional-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I am aware that this has an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/908758/bijection-between-an-infinite-set-and-its-union-of-a-countably-infinite-set). But I am wondering whether my proof is also valid.

I am reading the functional analysis book by Kolmogorov and Fomin and they ask to prove the above. But before that, they have shown that:

$$M \sim M \backslash A_2$$

In the following way:

1. Construct a countably infinite set from $M$:
   $$A = \{a_1, a_2, ..., a_n, ...\}$$
2. From $A$ construct two other countably infinite sets:
   $$A_1 = \{a_1, a_3, ..., a_{2n+1}, ... \} \text{ and } A_2 = \{a_2, a_4, ..., a_{2n}, ... \}$$

It is trivial to construct a surjective/bijective relationship between $A$ and $A_1$. Now consider that:

$$A \cup (M \backslash A) = M \text{ and } A_1 \cup (M \backslash A) = M \backslash A_2$$

Since $A \sim A_1$, we can then also conclude from the above equations that $M \sim M \backslash A_2$ because we can trivially construct a one-to-one mapping between $(M\backslash A)$ in the first equation and $(M \backslash A)$ in the second equation. Done...

Now from this result, I postulate that:

$$M \sim M \backslash A_2 \iff \begin{align*} & M \cup A_2 \sim (M \backslash A_2) \cup A_2 \\ &M \cup A_2 \sim M \end{align*} \tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Is my proof correct?

EDIT: by the way, I have noticed that in the linked answer they also assume that the countably infinite set is a subspace of the infinite set... I do not really like that answer, there are a couple of things that need clarification there, I doubt I will get an answer there if I comment given how old that question is.

**EDIT EDIT (potential proof)**: I think ignoring all of the above I might come up with a conceptual answer using Hilbert's infinite hotel paradox. First, we take an arbitrary countably infinite set from $M$, let's call it $B$. We now "merge" $B$ and $A$ (some arbitrary countably infinite set that is given). We do this using Hilbert's argument. We move every element/"guest" in set $B$ to it's even room. i.e. $n -> 2n$ (cardinality of naturals and evens is the same) by doing so we create a space for a countably infinite set $A$ inside of $B$. We have now created a countably infinite set $C$ in which every evenly numerated element is from $B$ and every oddly numerated element from $A$. Since the cardinality of $C$ did not change in the process, we have that $M \sim M \cup A$.

Comment: Is $A \subset M$ or not?

Comment: Ahh.. good point. Not necessarily.

Comment: In point 1, you construct $A$ from $M$. Shouldn't $A$ be given (according to the question in the title)?

Comment: Sorry, that $A$ is unrelated..